# Change Item Limit on Specific Category Page OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I have a custom Category tpl page in OpenCart. Just recently I was about to wrap the products loop with this code:

```
<?php  
$ids=array(444,443,145,97,459,460,454,451,450,449,445,446,447,448,457,456,387,385); // array of product id's   
?>


<?php 
foreach ($products as $product){  
  if(in_array($product['product_id'],$ids)) {
     //Display item
  }
}
?>
```

This code lets me choose specific products that I want to be displayed on this page. It works great! My problem now is that I have more than 16 products to display, and in my opencart setting my item limit is set to 16. I cannot change the settings because it would change all the other pages on my store.

Is there a way I can do this on the template page? Or, if I have to, the category controller? I would love to be able to add code to the loop. But Im up for any solution. Thanks!

Comment: Is this the limit used for pagination or some other one?

Comment: And what is wrong with the pagination? Just copy the pagination from default template back to this custom one. Once You paginate the same functionality will be preserved... But sir, please, check my answer to Your other question - this solution is really awful and all You need is to just unlink the products from that category that You do not want to be displayed...

Comment: have you created a separate category.tpl file or you just edited the original to add your code ? if you created a tpl file how do you instruct controller file to use that tpl file instead of default file, by how i mean what condition ? are all these products in same category ?

Comment: I have created a new category tpl. Basically what I'm trying to do is change the item limit number on specific pages. Right now all the pages have the same product limit that you set in the store settings.

Comment: @JCBiggar you are still avoiding the most important questions. i know what you want to do. but i want on what condition you are loading your new tpl file and how ? are all these products in same category ? don't be choosy on providing the info

Answer (score 0):

I just edited the Controller file:

```
        if ($category_info['category_id'] == '132'){
            $limit=1000;
        }
```

Now if my category has the id of 132, it will display all the products on that particular page.

Comment: exactly this is the reason why i was asking those question

Comment: sorry, I'm new to opencart so alot of things are hard to explain. Thanks though!